RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.integrations.bitsandbytes
I am trying to load an llm model in 4 bits precision. However, I got RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.integrations.bitsandbytes because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application after running the code below:
#device_map = {"": 0}

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, 
                                             device_map= "auto", 
                                             quantization_config=quantization_config,
                                             token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
model.eval()
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

I have installed accelerate, bitsandbytes, transformers, and all other packages but I am still getting the same error.
The only thing that I am seeing in the traceback is OSError.
I also restarted the kernel but it still did not work.

BitsAndBytes is not compatible with Windows-based systems. There is a particular fork which is not always guaranteed to work well, but it's actually supported in Linux, you should switch to Ubuntu to avoid the errors.
They actually state this in the documentation:

The bitsandbytes library is a lightweight Python wrapper around CUDA
custom functions, in particular 8-bit optimizers, matrix
multiplication (LLM.int8()), and 8 & 4-bit quantization functions.
The library includes quantization primitives for 8-bit & 4-bit
operations, through bitsandbytes.nn.Linear8bitLt and
bitsandbytes.nn.Linear4bit and 8-bit optimizers through
bitsandbytes.optim module.
There are ongoing efforts to support further hardware backends, i.e.
Intel CPU + GPU, AMD GPU, Apple Silicon. Windows support is quite far
along and is on its way as well.
Please head to the official documentation page:
https://huggingface.co/docs/bitsandbytes/main


BitsAndBytes is now working with pip on windows.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
